# Unused bits in addition/subtraction of long vectors

Tags: vhdl

I  try to write an ALU module in VHDL to calculate complex numbers. I try to keep everything simple and do not use any fancy algorithms like Booth or Vedic for multiplication. So basically, I use simple “+”, “-”, “*” operators on divided with “record” arrays:

```
-- a complex number
    type ComplexNr is record
        Re : signed(3 downto 0);
        Im : signed(3 downto 0);
    end record;
```

For output results of Addition/Subtraction and Multiplication I use vectors of the same length, hence double size of the input vector, i.e if Input_1 and Input_2 are 4 bits, my result vectors are 8 bits long. Now, if I do multiplication, everything works fine, however when I do addition/subtraction the unused bits appear as “U” in iSim.

The code for multiplication and addition is fairly simple:

```
-- complex multiplication
function c_mult(a, b : ComplexNr) return Complex_res is
    variable RetVal : Complex_res;
begin
    RetVal.Re := a.Re * b.Re - a.Im * b.Im;
    RetVal.Im := a.Re * b.Im + a.Im * b.Re;
    return (RetVal);

end function c_mult;

-- complex addition
function c_add(a, b : ComplexNr) return Complex_res is
    variable RetVal : Complex_res;
begin
    RetVal.Re := a.Re + b.Re;
    RetVal.Im := a.Im + b.Im;
    return (RetVal);

end function c_add;
```

So let’s say I add 0001 with 0010, I get “0011UUUU” for addition. How do you usually solve this problem? Do I have to initialize the unused bits with 0 explicitly?

Below is top design, which calls addition/subtraction and multiplication functions. Note that I initialize the result vectors to zero once. - Is it not enough? If needed I will provide test bench, but I just assign X and Y values, that's all.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

library work;
use work.complex_numbers.all;

entity cmplx_arithm is
    Port(
        -- Inputs:
        CLK       : in  STD_LOGIC;
        X         : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);   -- real X
        X_i       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);   -- imag X
        Y         : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);   -- real Y
        Y_i       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);   -- iamg Y

        -- Outputs:
        mux_res_r : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);   -- mux result
        mux_res_i : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        add_res_r : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);   -- add result
        add_res_i : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        sub_res_r : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);   -- sub result
        sub_res_i : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
    );
end cmplx_arithm;

architecture Behavioral of cmplx_arithm is

    -- set the result values to zero
     constant init_to_zero : Complex_res := (
                               Re => (others =>'0'),
                               Im => (others=> '0')
                               );


    signal A : ComplexNr;
    signal B : ComplexNr;

    signal resultMux : Complex_res := init_to_zero;
    signal resultAdd : Complex_res := init_to_zero;
    signal resultSub : Complex_res := init_to_zero;

begin
    A.Re <= signed(X);
    A.Im <= signed(X_i);
    B.Re <= signed(Y);
    B.Im <= signed(Y_i);

    -- multiplication
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            resultMux <= c_mult(A, B);
        end if;
    end process;

    -- addition
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            resultAdd <= c_add(A, B);
        end if;
    end process;

    -- subtraction
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            resultSub <= c_sub(A, B);
        end if;
    end process;

    mux_res_r  <= std_logic_vector(resultMux.Re);
    mux_res_i  <= std_logic_vector(resultMux.Im);
    add_res_r  <= std_logic_vector(resultAdd.Re);
    add_res_i  <= std_logic_vector(resultAdd.Im);
    sub_res_r  <= std_logic_vector(resultSub.Re);
    sub_res_i  <= std_logic_vector(resultSub.Im);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your testbench would be nice to have, because at the moment it's not clear what values are passed into your module to test the addition operation. From what I can see I'd guess you are trying to add two real numbers and didn't initialize the imaginary part in your testbench (i.e. X_i and Y_i are connected to uninitialized signals).

Comment: @damage, next time will do, but the problem was solved by user1155120. Nevertheless, it is apparent from the code that real and imaginary numbers are calculated separately, meaning it doesn't matter if i initialize X_i or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your c_add and (presumably) c_sub are not not written correctly

```
function c_add(a, b : ComplexNr) return Complex_res is
    variable RetVal : Complex_res;
begin
    RetVal.Re := a.Re + b.Re;
    RetVal.Im := a.Im + b.Im;
    return (RetVal);

end function c_add;
```

The length of the record elements of Complex_res you relate as being twice as long but the addition (and subtraction) will have a length matching the longest length of either operand (package numeric_std, signed "+").

You can resize the sums (and differences, c_add shown):

```
    resize(RetVal.Re := a.Re + b.Re,8);
    resize(RetVal.Im := a.Im + b.Im,8);
```

Note that if iSIM were fully compliant with the VHDL standard  you would have gotten runtime bounds check errors (unless disabled

The [ISim User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/plugin_ism.pdf) (UG660, v14.3) Chapter 3 Compilation and Simulation, Table 3-7: fuse, vhpcomp, and vlogcomp Command Options  entry for the --rangecheck option tells us "ISim always checks an index into an array for being within the allowed range." No mention I can find that there is check that there is an element in expression for every element in the target.

See IEEE Std 106-2008, 10.6.2 Simple variable assignments, 10.6.2.1 General, para 5:

> For the execution of a variable assignment whose target is a variable name, the variable name and the expression are first evaluated. A check is then made that the value of the expression belongs to the subtype of the variable, except in the case of a variable that is of a composite type (in which case the assignment involves a subtype conversion). ...

And 10.6.2.2 Composite variable assignments:

> If the target of an assignment statement is a name denoting a composite variable (including a slice), the value assigned to the target is implicitly converted to the subtype of the composite variable; the result of this subtype conversion becomes the new value of the composite variable.
>
> This means that the new value of each element of the composite variable is specified by the matching element (see 9.2.3) in the corresponding composite value obtained by evaluation of the expression. The subtype conversion checks that for each element of the composite variable there is a matching element in the composite value, and vice versa. An error occurs if this check fails.

Filling in the blanks to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package complex_numbers is
    type ComplexNr is record
        Re: signed (3 downto 0);
        Im: signed (3 downto 0);
    end record;

    type Complex_res is record
        Re: signed (7 downto 0);
        Im: signed (7 downto 0);
    end record;

    function c_mult(a, b:  ComplexNr) return Complex_res;
    function c_add(a, b:  ComplexNr) return Complex_res;
    function c_sub(a, b:  ComplexNr) return Complex_res;
end package;

package body complex_numbers is
    -- complex multiplication
    function c_mult(a, b:  ComplexNr) return Complex_res is
        variable RetVal:  Complex_res;
    begin
        RetVal.Re := a.Re * b.Re - a.Im * b.Im;
        RetVal.Im := a.Re * b.Im + a.Im * b.Re;
        return (RetVal);
    end function c_mult;

    -- complex addition
    function c_add(a, b:  ComplexNr) return Complex_res is
        variable RetVal:  Complex_res;
    begin
        RetVal.Re := resize(a.Re + b.Re,8);
        RetVal.Im := resize(a.Im + b.Im,8);
        return (RetVal);
    end function c_add;

    -- complex subtraction
    function c_sub(a, b:  ComplexNr) return Complex_res is
        variable RetVal:  Complex_res;
    begin
        RetVal.Re := resize(a.Re - b.Re,8);
        RetVal.Im := resize(a.Im - b.Im,8);
        return (RetVal);
    end function c_sub;   
end package body;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.complex_numbers.all;

entity cmplx_arithm is
    port (
        -- Inputs:
        CLK:        in  std_logic;
        X:          in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- real X
        X_i:        in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- imag X
        Y:          in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- real Y
        Y_i:        in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- iamg Y

        -- Outputs:
        mult_res_r:  out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- mult result
        mult_res_i:  out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        add_res_r:   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- add result
        add_res_i:   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        sub_res_r:   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- sub result
        sub_res_i:   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity cmplx_arithm;

architecture Behavioral of cmplx_arithm is

    -- set the result values to zero
     constant init_to_zero:  Complex_res := (
                               Re => (others =>'0'),
                               Im => (others=> '0')
                               );

    signal A:  ComplexNr;
    signal B:  ComplexNr;

    signal resultmult:  Complex_res := init_to_zero;
    signal resultAdd:  Complex_res := init_to_zero;
    signal resultSub:  Complex_res := init_to_zero;

begin
    A.Re <= signed(X);
    A.Im <= signed(X_i);
    B.Re <= signed(Y);
    B.Im <= signed(Y_i);

    -- multiplication
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            resultmult <= c_mult(A, B);
        end if;
    end process;

    -- addition
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            resultAdd <= c_add(A, B);
        end if;
    end process;

    -- subtraction
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            resultSub <= c_sub(A, B);
        end if;
    end process;

    mult_res_r  <= std_logic_vector(resultmult.Re);
    mult_res_i  <= std_logic_vector(resultmult.Im);
    add_res_r   <= std_logic_vector(resultAdd.Re);
    add_res_i   <= std_logic_vector(resultAdd.Im);
    sub_res_r   <= std_logic_vector(resultSub.Re);
    sub_res_i   <= std_logic_vector(resultSub.Im);

end architecture Behavioral;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cmplx_arithm_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of cmplx_arithm_tb is
    signal clk:        std_logic := '0';
    signal x:          std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal x_i:        std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal y:          std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal y_i:        std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    signal mult_res_r:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal mult_res_i:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal add_res_r:   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal add_res_i:   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal sub_res_r:   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal sub_res_i:   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
DUT:
    entity work.cmplx_arithm
        port map (
            CLK => clk,
            X => x,
            X_i => x_i,
            Y => y,
            Y_i => y_i,
            mult_res_r => mult_res_r,
            mult_res_i => mult_res_i,
            add_res_r => add_res_r,
            add_res_i => add_res_i,
            sub_res_r => sub_res_r,
            sub_res_i => sub_res_i
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 40 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        x <= "0100";
        x_i <= "0010";
        y <= "0010";
        y_i <= "0001";
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

gives:

[image: cmplx_arithm_tb.png]

(This was done with ghdl-0.33 hosted on OS X on a Mac with GTKWave)

Comment: thank you for the solution of the problem. So basically I can't add/sub two vectors and assign them to the longer one, even if the longer one is filled with zeros. I have to match the size.

I don't want to be ungrateful, but you didn't have to provide the whole code and such in depth explanation. The first sentence after my code and an example, was more then enough. And explained what went wrong. Nevertheless, thank you again for your help.

Comment: We tend to be myopic when supplied with bits and pieces. I reconstructed your code and noticed the problem during simulation,, the idea to test damage's comment. The solution could be to use the smaller type for the return value for c_add and c_sub. You could also use overload operators ("*", "+" and "-") instead of c_mult, c_add_and c_sub. VHDL has a very strong type system.